# Nodes request module throws an error after a while doing too many requests

Tags: node.js, heroku, request

Since recently I'm getting weird errors on my Express.js/Nodejs (`v10.16.0`) app that I have running on Heroku, that prevents us from making any requests to remote APIs.

I could narrow it down to the request module (`^2.88.0`), specifically the http-agent. It happens mostly happens after while, I assume after we've done some API requests.

```
TypeError: Agent is not a constructor
at Request.getNewAgent (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:698:26)
at Request.init (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:490:37)
at new Request (/app/node_modules/request/request.js:127:8)
at request (/app/node_modules/request/index.js:53:10)
```

Does someone knows whats going on?
Are the network interfaces blocked?